# bundler dev env setup

Tags: ruby, bundler, env

I am trying to setup bundler dev env and have gotten past the first steps from https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/DEVELOPMENT.md (done with `rake spec:deps` and `rake spec` but with two pendings jobs at the end http://fpaste.org/88485/13957673/raw/)

I don't know what the lib or bin path could be for $ alias dbundle='ruby -I /path/to/bundler/lib /path/to/bundler/bin/bundle'. Is it the lib and bin directories in the bundler source code directory?

Answer (score 0):

Once the second step of `rake spec` is done, you install with `gem build bundler.gemspec` and `gem install --local bundler-1.6.0.rc2.gem`.

What this means is when bundler itself is a gem and after the rake magic, you would need to install this git master version of bundler gem. To check if you are using the master version of bundler, run `bundle --version` on any directory and ti should return Bundler version 1.6.0.rc2 or something like that.

http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/bundle.1.html shows the args you can use on bundle binary.

To test out this master binary of bundle, create a new dir and do `bundle init`, add to it some gems to installed. For example:

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "hello-world"
gem "gem-man"

and run `bundle install`.
now:
sindhu@leh ~/code/rsoc/bunch_of_gemfiles % bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * bundler (1.6.0.rc2)
  * gem-man (0.3.0)
  * hello-world (1.2.0)

sindhu@leh ~/code/rsoc/bunch_of_gemfiles % bundle check
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied

sindhu@leh ~/code/rsoc/bunch_of_gemfiles % bundle platform                                         
Your platform is: x86_64-linux

Your app has gems that work on these platforms:
* ruby

Your Gemfile does not specify a Ruby version requirement.
```

Basically bundle is like pacman for gems but providing a exact subset of gems in the exact version you want. The only way to use it would be to use it would be use it on gems, that is to say: use this git master binary of bundle to install gems, test out if deps in a gemfile of an app are satisfied and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those should be the paths to the `bin` and `lib` directories in your cloned Bundler git repo.

The idea of the `dbundle` alias is that you can easily test out the changes you're making to Bundler by running `dbundle` in another project. Because the alias is pointing to your copy of the source code, you can see what it does without having to build and install the Bundler gem every time you make a change.